# Is this harmonic number in lowest terms?

Tags: rational-numbers, harmonic-numbers

Take the harmonic number

$$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n}=\frac{a}{b}$$

Define $a$ and $b$ as the actual integers produced by the summation - i.e., treat the numerator and denominator separately and do no clear like terms. Are $a$ and $b$ coprime?

It is clear that $b=m!$. But is $\frac{a}{m!}$ automatically in lowest terms 'straight out of the box'?

Instinct says yes, because there will always be a term in the numerator's sum that has a factor that is not shared with the other terms. But instinct is fallible. I've tried to read around, but I'm still not 100% clear; the assumption always seems to be that the fraction is in lowest terms.

Is my instinct correct? How would one prove it?

Comment: This is false for $m=4$.  For $m=10$, the gcd is $1440$.  Always good to try examples.

Comment: Have you checked this by computing the first ten or so harmonic numbers?

Comment: OK, I'm feeling dumb. Was looking at the algebra, and the answer was right there in the numbers. Many thanks, all of you. Is there any point posting an answer, or shall I just withdraw the question / delete?

Comment: Wolframalpha is a good tool to see the progression and compare to $m!$: [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%7BHarmonicNumber%5Bn%5D%2Cn%21%7D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C11%7D%5D)